# Pandas - append list to existing dataframe, same order as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, so I have a precreated dataframe and I try to append a list to it. In a simplified version the issues is below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': [],
                'Another' : [],
                'Third' : [],
                'Last' : []})
```

Then I do some stuff with a list:

```
new_obj = []
new_obj.append('1')
new_obj.append('2')
#I have to do the extend operation here
new_obj.extend(['3','4'])
```

Now I just want to add my `new_obj` list into my dataframe, objects are in the same order as I want them in dataframe.

So I just do:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = new_obj
```

And as result I have:

```
  Another Last One Third
0       1    2   3     4
```

Why?! Why it changes the column order to the aphabetic one. How do I preserve it when appending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `dict` in Python are unordered by nature. In order to specify the right order for the `DataFrame` you could write (or user `collections.OrderedDict`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': [],
                   'Another' : [],
                   'Third' : [],
                   'Last' : []}, columns=["One", "Another", "Third", "Last"])
```

On the other hand, if you don't really care about the order in the `DataFrame`, you could just explicitly define the columns int he `list` your are adding by simply using a `dict` instead:

```
new_obj = {"One" : 1, "Anohter" : 2, "Third" : 3, "Last" : 4}
df.loc[len(df.index)] = new_obj
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line `df.loc[len(df.index)] = new_obj` did not change the order of the columns.

Dictionary keys are unordered, so when you pass a dictionary to pd.DataFrame() to create your dataframe, your columns are not necessarily in the order you write them.

Try this to confirm:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': [],
                'Another' : [],
                'Third' : [],
                'Last' : []})

df.columns
```

> Index(['Another', 'Last', 'One', 'Third'], dtype='object')

...If you care about order of columns, instead initialize your df like this:

```
columns = ['one', 'another', 'third', 'last']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

as others answers mentioned, dictonary keys are not ordered. if you want ordered dict use orderddict as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

mydict = collections.OrderedDict((('One', []),
                ('Another', []),
                ('Third', []),
                ('Last', [])))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)

new_obj = []
new_obj.append('1')
new_obj.append('2')
#I have to do the extend operation here
new_obj.extend(['3','4'])
df.loc[len(df.index)] = new_obj
print df
```

results in

```
  One Another Third Last
0   1       2     3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`append`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with parameter `ignore_index=True`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns='One Another Third Last'.split())

new_obj = []
new_obj.append('1')
new_obj.append('2')
#I have to do the extend operation here
new_obj.extend(['3','4'])

# notice I created a `pd.Series` with `df.columns` as the index
df.append(pd.Series(new_obj, df.columns), ignore_index=True)

  One Another Third Last
0   1       2     3    4
```